# Kiosk customization is not supported on my device

Tags: android-management-api

I've set an application in `KIOSK` mode in the policy, with `systemNavigation` customization parameter set to `NAVIGATION_DISABLED`.

The policy is correctly applied, but according to the compliance report, the `kioskCustomization` setting in `UNSUPPORTED`.

Device is a Huawei P Smart running Android 9.1.0.

On which devices or Android versions this feature is available?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore the compliance warning for this policy. This is due to a bug in the API, which will be fixed within a few weeks to prevent an error in the compliance report.